# How to manage this unallocated space?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, windows-8.1

[image: disk overview]
That's how my whole drive looks like and the options that I can do with the Unallocated space. I have unallocated that space from the `C:/` drive. I want to make it Free and add it to the Free space on the most right.

I tried creating new partition out of it, so I can delete that partition and so it becomes a Free space, but I get an error that the disc already reached its limit of possible partitions. Furthermore, I cannot extend the `D:/` drive with that Unallocated space (with the logic that I would unallocate it from `D` and add it to the most-right Free space).

[image]

How can I achieve adding the `Unallocated space` to the `Free space` on the right?

Comment: You can’t, because that’s not where it physically resides. You’d need to move partitions, a rather dangerous process.

Comment: @DanielB - What if I clean everything on the right of `C:/` and make it `Free space`? My point is that I want to shring `C:/` and take space from it, without the need of reinstalling (so that I allocate the different partitions upon the installation process)?

Comment: have you tried using gparted?